# How to store data in memory while once select in js

Tags: javascript

Here is my code it works but once refresh it gets disappeared..

```js
function yesnoCheck(that) {
  if (that.value == "1") {
    // alert("check");
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
```

This is a script of the above code

Comment: save that information in your LocalStorage then if you want to persist it.

Comment: Store the data in `sessionStorage` or `localstorage`

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in `sessionStorage` or `localstorage`
The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. `sessionStorage` is similar to `Window.localStorage` ; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends.

You can store it easily with `localStorage.setItem('storeObj', JSON.stringify(myObj));`.

And if you go to another page you can get that object by doing this 
`var getObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));`.

Now you have your old object in variable `getObject`.

Sameway you can store retrieve data and object in `sessionStorage` too.